# Como deixa a ultima div de uma mesma classe colada na margin?

Tags: css

Eu tenho 3 `<div>` e elas utilizam a mesma classe, quero apenas colar a ultima na *margin*.

Já tentei:

```
.classe:last {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Utilize a pseudoclasse [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child). Ex: `.classe:last-child { margin-bottom: 0px }`

Answer (score 0):

Você  pode  usar

```
.class:last-child { margin-bottom:0px }
```

Porem nesse caso  qualquer  elmento  que seja o  ultimo  aplicará o estilo

Para garantir que o elemento seja apenas o div
utilize o  seguinte codigo

```
.class div:last-of-type{ margin-bottom:0px }
```

```css
.class div {
margin-bottom:10px;
background:pink;
float:left;
width:100%;
}
.class div:last-of-type{
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='class'>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  ok texto
</div>
```